# Ajuda função fread biblioteca C

Tags: c, funções

Alguém poderia me dizer porque esse trecho de código apenas começa a ler a partir do segundo elemento do arquivo?

E como eu poderia fazer para ler todos os registros do arquivo?

**Código que estou tentando utilizar para ler um arquivo txt**

```
 fread(vPtrContato, sizeof(contato_ref), 1, arquivo);
            printf("Nome: %s\n", contato_ref.primeiroNome);
            printf("Sobrenome: %s\n", contato_ref.segundoNome);
            printf("Telefone: %s\n", contato_ref.numeroTelefone);
            printf("E-mail: %s\n", contato_ref.email);
            fclose(arquivo);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu fgetc() na verificação ja faz avançar para o próximo elemento, ao invés disso recomendo que utilize:
 `while(feof(arquivo)){}`

rewind() volta ao começo do arquivo, fseek() é uma alternativa melhor más um pouco mais complicada de ser usada.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui ler a partir do primeiro elemento utilizando a função **rewind**

```
while ((caracteres = fgetc(arquivo)) != EOF) {

        rewind(arquivo);
        fread(vPtrContato, sizeof (contato_ref), 1, arquivo);
        printf("Nome: %s\n", contato_ref.primeiroNome);
        printf("Sobrenome: %s\n", contato_ref.segundoNome);
        printf("Telefone: %s\n", contato_ref.numeroTelefone);
        printf("E-mail: %s\n", contato_ref.email);
        printf("==================================\n");

        fclose(arquivo);  }
```